# Selenium Server and Windows Server compatibility

Tags: selenium

I want to run Selenium Server on a recent version of Windows Server so as to be able to test IE browsers as well as Firefox, Chrome, etc.

My choices for Windows Server are 2008 R2, 2008, or 2003. Are there any issues anyone is aware of with running it on any of those versions? Also, is there any reason to run it on a 32-bit version rather than a 64-bit version of Windows Server?

Answer (score 2):

I can say that I have worked with both 32 bit and 64 bit operating system using Selenium Server and the only requirement I am aware of is the - need to have java install on your system to be able to run Selenium Server. Reason - Selenium Server is written in java and needs java run time environment to be able to start the server.

Comment: Technically you don't need to install Java.  You could just copy a Java JDK/JRE directory over to the machine and start the Selenium node from it.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some browser compatibility issues on 64bit versions of Windows depending on how you want to start selenium server.  It cannot run as the System account.

There aren't many 64bit browsers yet.  If you can choose a 32bit OS, it will likely work better.